# WebHDFS and SequenceFiles

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

Is it true WebHDFS does not support `SequenceFiles`?

I can't find anything that says it does.  I have the usual small file problem and believe `SequenceFiles` would work well enough, but I need to use WebHDFS.  I need to create and then append to a `SequenceFile` via WebHDFS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's true.  There is no web API to append to a sequence file.

However you can append binary data, and if your sequence file is not block-compressed, you should be able to format your data on the client with relatively little effort.  You can do it by running your input through a sequence file writer on the client, and then using the output for uploading (either the whole file, or a slice representing the delta since last append).

You can read more about sequence file format [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/file-based-data-structures/id3555432).